# How to set the default page in lift

Tags: scala, lift

The question seems relatively simple, what I want is that when the user goes to:

```
http://somesite.ex/
```

they get the same content as if they had gone to:

```
http://somesite.ex/func1
```

That is, I want `func1` to be the "home page" for this site. Obviously I do not want to have a func1.html and an index.html which are just copies (or symlinks) of each other.

I have tried using the "welcome-file-list" section in web.xml, but that seems to be ignored. I am guessing that it should be an option that is specified in Boot, however I cannot find what that option would be.

I have tried the following snippet in Boot, but it did not do what I wanted:

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("BaseRewrite") {
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath(Nil, _, _, _), _, _) =>
    RewriteResponse("func1" :: Nil)
})
```

Comment: quick advice: did you try to redirect it other way round, to `ParsePath("func1"::Nil,_,_,_)` and `RewriteResponse("index" :: Nil)`? I guess that this way, ParsePath would eat all requests and end in cycle.

Comment: Thanks coubeatczech! While this was not the solution, it did lead me to the solution, which I have answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the correct redirect is:

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend(NamedPF("BaseRewrite") {
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("index" :: Nil, _, _, _), _, _) =>
    RewriteResponse("func1" :: Nil)
})
```

Thanks to the comment of coubeatczech which led me to the right answer.